# Using dual languages in Python speech recognition

Tags: python, text, speech

How can I add more languages in Python speech recognition? I tried the following codes but it didn't work. :(

```
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
    audio = robot_ear.listen(mic)

try:
    you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN")
    you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
    print("You: " + you)
except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
    print("I didn't get that")
except speech_recognition.RequestError:
    print("Sorry, I am brokem")
except:
    you = ""
```

Comment: If `you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio, language="en-EN")` throws an error, you will never reach `you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")`. On the other hand, if the first statement *doesn't* throw an error then the second statement will either throw an error or it will overwrite the value in `you`.

Comment: To Mr. Coleman, Thank you Sir, the first code works well until I add the second line "you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")", sometimes it throws an error sometimes it can recognize my voice. I don't know how to add one more language, how can they work together and recognize voices in both languages. Can you give me some suggestions?